# I can't ping the gateway IP (fe80::1) from the internal port in my fortigate 60f firewall

Tags: routing, ipv6, networking, ping, fortigate

[image]I am using a fortigate 60f firewall. I have configured it for both ipv4 and ipv6. I have used the **SD wan** (by adding wan1 and wan2) for load-balancing. Moreover, I have configure a default static route for both ipv4 and ipv6 (for the SD-wan). Further more I have configured ipvr4 and ipv6 policies too. This network works perfectly fine for the ipv4 configurations. Only my wan2 has ipv6 connectivity and the gateway is fe80::1. As **I mentioned above I have configure a default static route(gateway fe80::1), policies(from internal => sdwan) and sd wan rules(To send all the v6 traffic through wan2) for ipv6**. More over I have configured **my internal interface ipv6 address as fd00:1/64 and host(PC) connected to the internal as fd00::2/64**. **My wan2 interface ipv6 address is fe80::2/64**. ***

**Still I can't ping the gateway (fe80::1). Why is that? Where have I made the mistake?****

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you set the source IP address in `ping-options`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your ISP will simply drop any packets with ULA addresses (`fc00::/7`, which includes packets your `fd00::/64` network), so you cannot ping to your ISP from your ULA network.

Next, you are misusing the ULA addressing. You can locally assign addresses in the `fd00::/8` range, but the next 40 bits after the `fd` [must be randomly chosen](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4193#section-3.2.1) to give you a `/48` prefix from which you can get 65,536 `/64` networks for your use. Obviously, your `fd00::/64` is not using the required random 40-bit Global ID.

Also, you can only ping a Link-Local address in the Link-Local range (`fe80::/10`) from the same link of the address you are trying to ping  [Traffic to and from Link-Local addresses cannot leave the link (be routed).](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.6) All IPv6 interfaces use the same Link-Local network, so you must use a Zone ID (host OS-specific) when using Link-Local addresses. For example, on a Windows PC, you would `ping fe80::1%2` or something like `ping fe80::1%eth0` on a Linux host.

---

> I can't ping the gateway IP (fe80::1) from the internal port in my
> fortigate 60f firewall

That would be correct because you are trying to ping a Link-Local address from a different Link, and you cannot do that. You are also wanting your ISP to respond to a ULA addressed host, but the ISP should properly drop any packets with ULA addresses.

> Still I can't ping the gateway (fe80::1). Why is that? Where have I
> made the mistake?

I explained why, and I have pointed out your mistakes. You will never be able to ping a Link-Local address from a different link, and your ISP would drop any ULA traffic, anyway.

Comment: Thanks :) So theres no way I can ping the gateway in this scenario right?

Comment: Not the way you want. You could ping the `fe80::1` gateway address from the Fortigate interface connected on the same link (assuming the ISP has not disabled ICMP echo responses), but Link-Local addresses cannot be reached from a different link. Notice that the Fortigate and all other hosts on your LAN also use the same Link-Local network.

Comment: @EcstasyEntertainment, as I wrote in my comment to your [so] question, "_Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration, neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present. Routers must not forward any packets with Link-Local source or destination addresses to other links._"

Comment: Hey Thanks Ron. I was working on this for like 10days. Well you helped me to figure out that I was working on something which will never happen :) Thanks alot :)